# How to sign a large file for random-access reading?

Tags: rsa, signature

I need to write an "Authoring" application which produces large files. These files must be signed so that the "Consuming" application knows that it was authored with a matching key.
The consuming application must access the signed files read-only, with random access. This means it will not read the full file but still must check that the read bytes are signed.

I have thought cutting the data into 64k blocks and sign these blocks individually using a RSA private key with Crypto++.

1. Is there a RSA scheme which produces fixed size signatures?
2. The last block can be as small as 1 byte. Is there any cryptographical risk doing this?
3. Is this globally a good idea?

Comment: Compute a Merkle Tree Hash and sign its root. Merkle trees support efficiently proving that certain blocks belong to a root by looking at uncle hashes.

Comment: Signing individual blocks allows an attacker to combine blogs from several files you signed or even reorder the blocks within a single file, resulting in a file that you never signed.

Comment: What about just adding an index and a file unique id to every block and sign it with the block data? You prevent both reordering and file mixing.

Comment: Thanks for the Merkle tree hint, I will read about it. It is maybe an overkill solution, though.

Comment: With that approach you also need  to tag the last block or authenticate the length, otherwise you'll suffer from truncation attacks. (Personally I still prefer the hash-tree or at least hash-list approach).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is there a RSA scheme which produces fixed size signatures?

Normally RSA signatures are fixed size. Depending on encoding and the details included, the length may vary by at least a few bytes, though. There is usually a known maximum at least.

> 2. The last block can be as small as 1 byte. Is there any cryptographical risk doing this?

No. As long as a good signature scheme (including a secure hash and proper padding in the case of RSA) is used the length of the data signed does not matter.

> 3. Is this globally a good idea?

Firstly, signing each block individually does not allow verifying that their order is correct – an attacker could reorder the blocks and the corresponding signatures. You would need to add at least an index of the block to the signed data to verify that. (You likely also need to sign the file identity and length to prevent moving blocks between files or leaving data off the end.)

It also seems somewhat inefficient — RSA signatures are quite long and computing them is relatively time-consuming. But you know best whether the performance is sufficient or the space usage a problem in your use case.

Signing a [hash list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_list) or hash tree of the data would allow storing a shorter signature and verifying blocks faster — you only need to verify a signature of the hashes once, then it suffices to check that each block hashes to the correct value. It would also take care of verifying the ordering. However, it would require reading and verifying a length-dependent list/tree of hashes before reading the actual data, which may be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the reading of the hash data would become an issue quickly. Even with a 64 byte (512 bit) hash the minimal size of the list would 64 bytes per 64 KiB block. A quick calculation shows that you're already up to 64 MiB before the hashes take up more space then a single block. Personally I would go for a larger block size if really big files are concerned. Modern computers and even phones should have no issue with 1 MiB blocks minimum - leading to a 16 x 16 = 256 fold increase before the hash list overtakes the block size (16 GiB) - if that matters at all.

Comment: In order to prevent an attacker to mixing blocks between files, adding a file id to the index in every block is also required. Could you add this to the answer?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, size-wise probably not, but I can imagine cases where you would need all authentication data to be stored right next to the block, so that true random access is possible - i.e. there is no access to data except to an authenticated block.

Comment: @galinette, added, but even it would not be enough to prevent an attacker from dropping blocks off the end, so a hash list/tree is better.

Comment: @otus That's probably not a good idea for this answer. Some global data for the file would be required to make this efficient. || galinette I'm not sure you follow the idea of a hash list. As long as the signed hash list is linked to the specific file then the signature should be enough to make sure that blocks are not swapped or switched out. You may of course want to add meta data to the structure that contains the list. A precise time stamp and or unique identifier for the file would be a *very* good idea. But this is true for any signature of course.

Comment: dropping blocks of the end is not a problem here, as 1)random access will only be done at offsets deduced from reading the data from the beginning and 2)the internal format has a terminator

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will choose between both approaches. The biggest issue with hash list is that I do not know in advance the number of blocks, so I cannot reserve space for it at the beginning of the file. And prepending data to a file makes you write the full data twice.

Comment: @galinette, simplest solutions are to store the hash list in a separate file or to append it (with a final length field to easily find where it starts).

Comment: Free hint: You may want to look into memory mapping of files to make this as efficient as possible. I/O speed will be the main bottleneck.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : you can't say this unless you know which device I'm writing to... It may be anything from a ramdisk to a floppy.

Comment: ... otherwise it is very possible that the I/O speed will be the main bottleneck ... (Intel Core 2 1.83 did 100 MiB/s in 2009 - single threaded - source Crypto++). It's likely to save you at least an additional *spurious* copy to memory if you memory map the file.